# NoActionBar still displaying on physical devices

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-emulator, android-actionbar

So here is my problem : I put NoActionBar on my themes and when i run my app in an emulated device no action bar are shown (so everthing is fine) BUT when I install and run the app on my smartphone (galaxy S8 API 28 if it has anything to with it) an action bar is still displaying why so?

Here is the themes.xml file :

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.DTTREALESTATE" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_gray</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/light</item>
        <!-- Navigation bar color -->
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I tried to use the DarkActionBar to see what would be display on my smartphone but it didn't do anything it only affect the emulated devices... To be honest I have ABSOLUTLY no idea how to solve this.

Comment: please send your manifest codes here

Answer (score 1):

Please add these lines in both of themes.xml files (Day and night).

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change it in both (night and normal one)themes.xml files

Comment: This looks like a comment rather than an answer

Comment: It says that I don't have enough reputation to comment,should i delete my answer ?